# Why is PHP-IMAP with Gmail logging a bunch of nonsense of late?

Tags: php, email, gmail, imap, spam

In the last weeek, I've received an extreme amount of SPAM e-mails. It's constant. At least 100x more than normal. I've blackholed countless domains at this point, but they seem to have endless ones. And a huge amount of them are so broken that they only appear in my (custom made) e-mail client's "broken" category, where it puts e-mails that are *complete* garbage.

Now, I've noticed that PHP-IMAP (that is, the IMAP functions built into PHP, which I use to talk to Gmail to fetch e-mails) has started logging a bunch of stuff like this:

```
Unterminated mailbox: issacromero25@imap.gmail.com
Unterminated mailbox: moorem@imap.gmail.com
Invalid mailbox list: "marshallmark
Invalid mailbox list: "dunnenoel5@gm
Unterminated mailbox: pearodavid058@gmail
Unterminated mailbox: white@imap.gmail.com
Unterminated mailbox: 3061jlj@gmail.
Invalid mailbox list: "milesp70@y
Unterminated mailbox: goldmandepressed2886@gmai
Invalid mailbox list: "res
Unterminated mailbox: pearodavid058@gmail
Invalid mailbox list: "braydenmccos
Invalid mailbox list: "b
Unterminated mailbox: passr@yaho
Unterminated mailbox: ro@imap.gmail.com
```

Clearly, they are doing something horribly wrong, probably on purpose, but why on Earth does IMAP try to open mailboxes named like that?

I spent an enormous amount of time on my IMAP code long ago, and at this point, I really thought it was rock solid. Then this suddenly happens. You can never count on anything staying non-broken for long, apparently...

My PHP code simply `imap_open`s whatever `imap_list` returns. Why does Gmail return a bunch of broken "mailboxes"? Have the spammers found a way to add "mailboxes" ("categories") automatically to Gmail accounts? Or what is going on?

Comment: Are you sure your site is not hacked, and so that hackers are trying to send mail using your server? Check all files (also hidden one) that must be equal to your development sources (or with backups, but attackers will often hid in your server for months or years). Check also your web server logs for unusual pages (maybe just using unvalidated user parameters)

Comment: Stop your server as early as possible until you find the reason. Better a server down for some time then a server in many blacklists (which seems never expire)

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi While I cannot fully rule out some sort of compromise of either my machine (it's actually not a server) and/or my Gmail account, I do keep very good tabs on all outgoing e-mails as well, and they have not sent a single one out if they have somehow broken into my system.

Comment: It could be complaining about malformed mailbox lists, in say, your To, From, etc. lines while it is trying to parse an email.  It looks like a lot of them have bad quoting....